# How to find out the PID which generates traffics to port 9229 in MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook, netstat, tcpdump, lsof

There are unknown traffics to port 9229 in my MacBook.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i any -n port 9229
......
12:10:39.176502 IP6 ::1.62261 > ::1.9229: Flags [S], seq 638850191, win 65535, options [mss 16324,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1096627032 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:10:39.176520 IP6 ::1.62261 > ::1.9229: Flags [S], seq 638850191, win 65535, options [mss 16324,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1096627032 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:10:39.176535 IP6 ::1.9229 > ::1.62261: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 638850192, win 0, length 0
12:10:39.176538 IP6 ::1.9229 > ::1.62261: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
12:10:39.176741 IP6 ::1.62262 > ::1.9229: Flags [S], seq 3150040653, win 65535, options [mss 16324,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1096627032 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:10:39.176755 IP6 ::1.62262 > ::1.9229: Flags [S], seq 3150040653, win 65535, options [mss 16324,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1096627032 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:10:39.176768 IP6 ::1.9229 > ::1.62262: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3150040654, win 0, length 0
12:10:39.176772 IP6 ::1.9229 > ::1.62262: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
12:10:39.176892 IP 127.0.0.1.62263 > 127.0.0.1.9229: Flags [S], seq 3515509457, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1096627032 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:10:39.176908 IP 127.0.0.1.62263 > 127.0.0.1.9229: Flags [S], seq 3515509457, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1096627032 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:10:39.176927 IP 127.0.0.1.9229 > 127.0.0.1.62263: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3515509458, win 0, length 0
12:10:39.176931 IP 127.0.0.1.9229 > 127.0.0.1.62263: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
12:10:39.177042 IP 127.0.0.1.62264 > 127.0.0.1.9229: Flags [SEW], seq 204257524, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1096627032 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:10:39.177059 IP 127.0.0.1.62264 > 127.0.0.1.9229: Flags [SEW], seq 204257524, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 1096627032 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:10:39.177078 IP 127.0.0.1.9229 > 127.0.0.1.62264: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 204257525, win 0, length 0
12:10:39.177083 IP 127.0.0.1.9229 > 127.0.0.1.62264: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
......
```

But I can't find the process with `netstat`.

```
$ netstat -an | grep 9229
$
```

Or with `lsof`.

```
$ sudo lsof -i | grep 9229
$
```

With `tcpdump` I find the string `Google.Chrome` in some of the packets. So I think probably Chrome generates these traffics.

1. Could anybody help me to find out the PID which generates these traffics?
2. If it's Chrome, how can I stop Chrome from generates the traffics without closing Chrome?

Thanks.

Comment: It's the default port for Microsoft Visual Studio Code Node Debug which uses a Chrome debug protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the `default port` explanation. Any idea about finding the PID?

Comment: For a tcp socket `lsof -nPi tcp:9229` or `lsof -nPi | grep 9229`. See [How can I find which process sends data to a specific port?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56988/how-can-i-find-which-process-sends-data-to-a-specific-port) on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: These connection attempts are all failing because *nothing* is listening on 9229. The only packets that appear to come from 9229 are TCP Resets, which are being generated by the TCP stack itself because there are no processes listening on 9229. That's why looking for 9229 is failing. Instead, you'd have to try to predict the next ephemeral port number and hope to run lsof in the split second that the client process is making an attempt.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322089/node-js-port-3000-already-in-use-but-it-actually-isnt

Answer (score 0):

Use nettop.

Tip: Make your Terminal window as wide as possible. nettop has tons of columns but it won't display them unless the window is wide enough.